# Real life objects that you relate to algebraic structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

I am aware that there are questions asking about real life applications of abstract algebra. My question is, when you were working on something, doing something, have you ever thought about some algebraic structures that you relate to the objects that were dealing with? What did you think?

*An example: There is a game called "minecraft". I played it for a few times. In the game, there were some building blocks that you use to build a house, cage etc. Also, there were some rivers and I was able to change the direction of the flow. So, I was thinking about building an abstract structure, add some properties, reshape it, divide it into smaller structures that have hereditary properties. There were also some structures that were stayed invariant under my actions.*

Answer (score 1):

The Rubik's Cube. Actually a great toy to learn about commutators.

Answer (score 1):

Wall papers, using the groups of symmetries.